# Highlighting square faces

Tags: mesh, interface, edit-mode, vertices, faces

i have got a question about visual blender help; is there a way to automatically highlight only square faces of the model? So when editing mesh, the faces remain highlighted (like seams are highlighted).

Comment: Not to my knowledge. You can hide selected faces with H (and ALT-H to unhide) but not mark them visually while editing.

Comment: AFAIK this isn’t possible but with add-on or python, but not vanilla Blender. You can select them…but I think you don’t want that, right?

Comment: I'd like to just highlight them visually only, like in a different color or something, so when i'm editing the mesh, i could just orbit around the object in either Solid or Wireframe modes and see where square faces of the mesh are, instead of triangles or other shapes.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind modelling in *Material Preview*, (which can often be useful in other ways too, with other purpose-built EEVEE shaders, for modelling,) then maybe you could just put together a little GN modifier and shader combination:

[image]

Which will react to your edits:

[image]